# Using ValueChangeListener with Richfaces suggestion Box

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to use Richfaces suggestion box.  Based on the value selected from the suggestionbox, I am trying to change outputtext value next to it.

Here is my xhtml code:

```
<td align="left">
    <h:inputText onchange="submit();" immediate="true" id="productname" valueChangeListener="#{salesBean.updateProductRate}" autocomplete="false"/>
</td>
<td align="left">
    <h:outputText id="rate" binding="#{salesBean.productRate}"/>
</td>

<rich:suggestionbox width="290" suggestionAction="#{salesBean.suggest}" var="state" for="productname">      
    <f:facet name="nothingLabel">
        <h:outputText value="No Products found" />
    </f:facet>    
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Select Product" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{state.name}"/>
    </h:column>
</rich:suggestionbox>
```

When I type 'a' in the inputtext (for example) Richfaces suggestionbox shows the list of names starting with letter 'a'.  If I select one of the names (say 'asd'), only 'a' which I typed earlier gets submitted in the form.

How to make the whole name 'asd' to get submitted in the form?  Please help

Thanks in advance

(I am using JSF 1.2 along with Richfaces 3.3.2)

**Updated Code**

```
<td align="left">
                                <h:inputText immediate="true" id="productname" autocomplete="false">

                                </h:inputText>

                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <h:outputText id="rate" binding="#{salesBean.productRate}"/>
                            </td>

<rich:suggestionbox width="290"
suggestionAction="#{salesBean.suggest}" var="state" for="productname">

<f:facet name="nothingLabel">
            <h:outputText value="No Products found" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Select Product" />
            </f:facet>
<h:column>
   <h:outputText value="#{state.name}"/>
</h:column>
<a4j:support event="onselect" action="#{salesBean.updateProductRate}" reRender="rate">
             <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{state.name}" target="#{salesBean.selectedProductName}" />
</a4j:support>
```

This is my java code

```
HtmlOutputText productRate = new HtmlOutputText();

public String updateProductRate()
    {
    System.out.println("Successfully entered ");
    SalesDAO dao = new SalesDAO();


    //getProductRate().setValue(dao.fetchRateForProductEntered(evt.getNewValue().toString()));

    //selectedProductName = dao.fetchRateForProductEntered(evt.getNewValue().toString());

    return "success";
}

public HtmlOutputText getProductRate() {
    return productRate;
}


public void setProductRate(HtmlOutputText productRate) {
    this.productRate = productRate;
}

public List<ProductSuggestOBJ> suggest(Object input)
{
    SalesDAO dao = new SalesDAO();
    List<ProductSuggestOBJ> suggestionList = new ArrayList<ProductSuggestOBJ>();

    String userInput = (String)input;

    if(!userInput.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        suggestionList = dao.suggestProductFromDatabase(userInput);
    }

    return suggestionList;
}

private String selectedProductName;




public String getSelectedProductName() {
    return selectedProductName;
}


public void setSelectedProductName(String selectedProductName) {
    this.selectedProductName = selectedProductName;
}
```

The same error remains.  Plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to select a product from the suggestion box and then call the `#{salesBean.updateProductRate}` to calculate the product rate for the selected product.

You can do it by directly attaching an `onselect` event to the suggestion box using `a4j:support` instead of using the `valueChangeListener` of the `h:inputText` that the suggestion box provides value to.

```
<h:inputText  immediate="true" id="productname" />
 <br/>
 <h:outputText id="rate" value="#{salesBean.productRate}"/>
<rich:suggestionbox width="290" suggestionAction="#{salesBean.suggest}" var="state" for="productname">      
    <f:facet name="nothingLabel">
        <h:outputText value="No Products found" />
    </f:facet>    
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Select Product" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{state.name}"/>
    </h:column>
    <a4j:support event="onselect" action="#{salesBean.updateProductRate}" reRender="rate">
                 <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{state.name}" target "#{salesBean.selectedProductName}" />
    </a4j:support>
</rich:suggestionbox>
```

In the `salesBean` ,  add the `selectedProductName` properties and its getter and setter. In the `updateProductRate()` , you use the `selectedProductName` to calculate the product rate and assign the result to the `productRate`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Sorry for the delay.  Problem is not yet solved.  Plz check my updated code.

Comment: Do the `setSelectedProductName()` and `updateProductRate()` method get called after selecting a value from the suggestion list? BTW, 
I do not spot any errors in your updated code .

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment. I was little confused. Your updation works perfectly.  Thanks!